# Adding non gmail custom email adress as new user on google webmaster tool

Tags: google-search-console, gmail

I have tried adding my company mail adress as an user on google webmaster tool.

I know that company email needs to be associated with a gmail account.

In order to do that i have added my company mail adress   myname@company.com to my gmail account myname@gmail.com as an alternate email adress following the steps here https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/176347?hl=en

However when i try to add my company mail adress myname@company.com as new user on google webmaster tool it says

> Can't associate myname@company.com with any Google account

I think i have done all the required steps.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Think about Search Console as a *service*. You are adding users to this service. Each user needs to have a Google Account but **does not** need to have Gmail - which in fact is another *service*.

In order to create a Google Account without signing up for Gmail *service*, visit https://accounts.google.com/signup and pick "I prefer to use my current email address" option. After filling the form and confirming email, you can then add that newly created Google Account to each of your Search Console services.

Personally, I find this approach much better than mixing work related stuff/access with personal Google Accounts.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. This approach is better indeed.